# How to install gulp globally

Tags: npm, gulp

I am trying to istall gulp globally at work computer and find some error

```
> PS C:\OpenServer\domains\the_witcher_3_wild_hunt> npm install gulp -g
> npm ERR! path \\DOM-PDC\HomeWin7$\ npm ERR! code ELOOP npm ERR! errno
> -62 npm ERR! syscall stat npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, stat '\\DOM-PDC\HomeWin7$\'
> 
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
> C:\Devel\nodejs\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-31T08_56_13_632Z-debug.log
```

---

**Edit:**

- I have read [this related issue](https://npm.community/t/installing-a-module-in-the-global-location-when-a-previous-version-exists-results-in-a-symbolic-link-loop/7665) and can confirm that no previous version of `gulp` is installed.
- I have also cleared the [npm cache](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache.html) by running; `npm cache clean --force`, however the same problem still persists.

Comment: My **guess** is it might be something to do with trying to use `\\DOM-PDC\HomeWin$\` ... not sure whether this is because of where your "user area" under Windows is, the `prefix` setting within `npm` or something else. Can you **(a)** install any other package globally under these conditions (YES => problem with gulp); or **(b)** install it when your "global" area is a local drive (YES => problem installing to network drive).

Comment: @TripeHound Thank you. I will try and inform here about results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is about "prefix", as it suggest @TripeHound.
If you have similar problem you can find answers [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-node-package-manager/)

Comment: Glad I could nudge you in the right direction. However, while it's perfectly fine to answer your own question, so-called "link only" answers are frowned upon (because the link could die in the future). It would be best if you can add the essential details from that page to your answer (with proper acknowledgement/reference to the source).